# Postgres how to join table A,B when B is partial to A

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have two tables:

Table A - big table

```
key,value1
```

table B - smaller table not all keys exists on this table

```
keyint, value2
```

i would like to combine into a third table - table C

```
key,value1,value2
```

(where value2 will apear, if exists and if not empty or 0 or NULL)

how do i do that in postgres?

Comment: The `left join` is the correct thing to do. Maybe the `limit 10000` only shows you those rows that actually have a match in b?

Comment: thanks i found the solution, is left outer join!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name +1 for the fiddle, but you slightly misread the quesition: value1 is not in table B so it's not ambiguous.

Comment: @yaron: `left join` and `left outer join` do absolutely the same thing. And you should **not** edit your question to reflect your solution. This way nobody will later know what the actual problem was, add an answer instead. And as I said, adding  `outer` will not have changed anything.

Comment: @BellevueBob: thanks. This indeed escaped me somehow.

Comment: @yaron Please do not revise your question with an answer; use the "answer box".  You should only revise questions to make the **question** better.  Otherwise it loses all context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Added as edit to question by author, so posting as CW here):

I have found the solution:

```
SELECT key,value1,value2
          FROM A as A1
          left outer join B on A1.key =B.keyint limit 10000;
```

The left outer join will take all records from `A` and put values if they exists on `B`.